# Is there a difference between these two op-amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I find different op-amp configurations all over the places, with respect to where +Vcc is connected -

[image]
[image]

(**1**) Are these two one and the same?

(**2**) What if the positive power terminal is connected to a negative power supply and the negative terminal to a positive power supply?

Image:Google

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it demonstrates no effort at basic research into op-amps using google and the wealth of other beginner 101 sites for people wanting to use op-amps or any chip/IC/transistor. These are very basic questions that are best served by google et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. You let the magic smoke out.